# How to do Resize using Java and Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, resize

How to do Resize using Java and Selenium?

[Link](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Code I have been trying:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
        
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement resize = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'resizable']/div[3]"));
        //WebElement resize = driver.findElement(By.id("resizable"));
        new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(resize, 400, 400).perform();
    }
```

the this is the below error:

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move
> target out of bounds
```

Comment: you can only resize the inner-rectangle within the outer rectangle. Get the bounds of outer rectangle first and see to what possible values you can resize the inner-rectangle.

Comment: Can I get some update on the below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you'd shared earlier, I have made a few changes in that, Please see the below code.

The web element is in iframe, therefore we will have to first switch to the iframe and then use action class `dragAndDropBy` with the following properties:

```
(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

**Code:**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.demo-frame")));
WebElement resizeButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se")));
action.dragAndDropBy(resizeButton, 100, 50).build().perform();
```